# New field widget (for custom field type) does not save data

Tags: input-formats, entities

I am trying to make my own field type. I order to do it I modify field_example from drupal examples.

I added new widget_form (declared also in widget_info). The problem is, value is not saved in the database using my widget.

CODE:

```
function field_example_field_widget_info(){
  return array(
      'field_example_text' => array(
      'label' => t('Choose game type using text input'),
      'field types' => array('field_example_rgb'),
    ),
    'field_example_list' => array(
      'label' => t('Choose game type using select'),
      'field types' => array('field_example_rgb'),
    ),
  );  

}

function field_example_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $value = isset($items[$delta]['rgb']) ? $items[$delta]['rgb'] : '';

  $widget = $element;
  $widget['#delta'] = $delta;

    $options = array('Tic Tac Toe', 'Memory', 'Mastermind');
    $default_value = array(1,2,3);

  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'field_example_text':
      $widget += array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => $value,
        // Allow a slightly larger size that the field length to allow for some
        // configurations where all characters won't fit in input field.
        '#size' => 1,
        '#maxlength' => 2,
      );
      break;

    case 'field_example_list':

    $widget += array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#default_value' => $default_value,

        // Do not display a 'multiple' select box if there is only one option.
        //'#multiple' => $multiple && count($options) > 1,
        '#options' => $options,
      );
        break;
  $element['rgb'] = $widget;
  return $element;
}

Validation was also modified:

function field_example_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    if (!empty($item['rgb'])) {
      if (!preg_match('@^[1-3]$@', $item['rgb'])) {
        $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
          'error' => 'field_example_invalid',
          'message' => t('Invalid game number: 1 - 3.'),
        );
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Value is not saved into database using ..._list, but is saved using ..._text and proper values (while adding; in the adding form) are displayed in the source code (in both case). I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have hook_field_is_empty()?

Comment: The title is misleading. This is about field widgets, not field formatters.